# The order of function doesn't allow me to write reusable codes in c++

Tags: c++

I have two functions that is dependent on each other, but the order of the function in C++ limit my ability to write reusable codes. For example let say, I want to use functionA in a functionB then

```
functionB has to be above functionA.
```

but what if

functionB is using functionA and functionA is using functionB as well? it will gives error

Here's the code, and the order of the functions in c++

```
void getAnswer(string answer) {

            mainProgram();

}

void mainProgram() {
   getAnswer("awesome");

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   

    mainProgram();


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see mainProgram() is using getAnswer() function and vice versa.

I can just solve this problem by deleting the getAnswer() function and simply throw every code from getAnswer() to mainProgram() but the problem with that , is I will write a repetitive code for about 5 times, and it will look really messy.

Comment: Am I the only one to notice an "infinite" recursion here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to *forward-declare* your function:

```
//forward declaration
void mainProgram();

void getAnswer(string answer) {
    //sees the declaration above, doesn't need the definition
    mainProgram();
}

//now we define the function
void mainProgram() {
   getAnswer("awesome");
}
```

This kind of thing should be covered in your introductory book. If you don't have a good introductory book, [get one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Also note that you will need to terminate this mutual recursion at some point.

Comment: infinite recursion, how do i solve it?

Comment: @airsoftFreak With your brain and an exit condition.

Comment: @Blacktempel Instructions not clear, smeared brain all over C++.

Comment: Have a check like `if (shouldExit) return; else mainProgram();`.

Comment: Got it, i thought i need to do something exquisite like using c++ special method or something.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Define the names and parameters of the functions first, and then declare their body. This allows two functions to be dependent on each other.

```
void mainProgram(); // this is a declaration of your function.

void getAnswer(string answer) // the body of the function which can call the declared function.
{
    mainProgram();
}

void mainProgram() // the body of the function which was declared earlier.
{
    getAnswer("awesome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is infinite of function calling .However if your not sure about order function calling and it's declaration, use forward declare in the beginning  of the file.